# Android chat listview not scrolling totally

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, listview

I have a ListView of a chat that is not scrolling till the end of all the messages. I can't figure out why this is happening. If I send a new message and the length of all the messages in the chat is more than a page so i nedd to scroll over to see the message i succeed to scroll but not enogh to see all the messages.

My Layout XML code here :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@drawable/cool_background3">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/messages_view"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:divider="#fff"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topBar" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_chatbox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext_chatbox"
        android:hint="Enter message"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="6"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_chatbox_send"
        android:text="send"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/myColor"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/topBar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_of_user"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tomnaor"
        android:textColor="@color/myColor"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emotion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Happy Chat"
        android:textColor="#939393"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/name_of_user"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name_of_user"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: why is your listview height "0dp"? Are you changing it programmatically?

Comment: @SafalSharma It's the way to tell "take the place left by ohter".

Comment: @vincrichaud Yes I got it but, maybe the issue might be caused by not properly changing it programmatically. Thank you

Comment: @SafalSharma To put hieght="0dp" is correct, You don't have to change it programmatically later. It tells the system to always adapt the heigh of this view to take the remaining space.

Comment: @vincrichaud Thank You, never knew this before :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your ListView xml:

```
android:stackFromBottom="true"
android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
```

For reference:

- [stack from bottom](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView#attr_android%3AstackFromBottom)
- [transcript mode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView#attr_android%3AtranscriptMode)

Comment: plz explain more

Answer (score 0):

you are not given proper constraint to your ListView.

**You may try this way :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/cool_background3">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/messages_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:divider="#fff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/layout_chatbox"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topBar" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_chatbox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext_chatbox"
            android:hint="Enter message"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="6"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_chatbox_send"
            android:text="send"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/myColor"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/topBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_of_user"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tomnaor"
            android:textColor="@color/myColor"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emotion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Happy Chat"
            android:textColor="#939393"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/name_of_user"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/name_of_user"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```